# How to get the selected value of a drop-down list with JavaScript/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-select

I'm new to JavaScript and require some help, I have as yet been unable to find a solution to this problem and would appreciate any help if possible. I thank you in advance.

Ok, I have two drop-down lists and what I would like to do is create a function that would allow me to print out a value depending on the combination of options selected. for example, if "iPhone" is selected in drop down one, then "button" is selected in drop-down two it would display the cost of that repair in a text box.

```
 <select name="phones">
<option value="iphone">iphone</option>
<option value="blackberry">blackberry</option>
<option value="HTC">HTC</option>
<option value="Samsung">Samsung</option>
</select>

<select name="repair">
<option value="button">button</option>
<option value="battery">batter</option>
<option value="screen">screen</option>
<option value="back">back</option>
</select>
```

So lets say that i selected iphone then button a value would display but if i selected blackberry then button a different value would display , i have tried event listener and i have tried doing this using a button, but i just cannot seem to get the code right please help if you can.

Thank you

Comment: What's the cost of iphone and button?

Comment: That's my problem the cost of button is lets say £10 when iphone is selected but this needs to change when blackberry  is selected,lets say to £5, I am not even sure if this is possible with Java script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to add your own price list and items... but this should hopefully guide you in the right direction...

```js
$(function() {
  var priceList = {};
  
  priceList.iphoneRepair = {
    "button": "1",
    "battery": "2",
    "screen": "3",
    "back": "4"
  };
  priceList.blackberryRepair = {
    "button": "1.1",
    "battery": "2.1",
    "screen": "3.1",
    "back": "4.1"
  };
  priceList.SamsungRepair = {
    "button": "1.2",
    "battery": "2.2",
    "screen": "3.2",
    "back": "4.2"
  };
  priceList.HTCRepair = {
    "button": "1.3",
    "battery": "2.3",
    "screen": "3.3",
    "back": "4.3"
  };
  
  console.log( priceList );

  $("#phones, #repair").on('change', function() {
    var repairItem = $("#phones").val() + "Repair";
    console.log( repairItem );
    console.log( priceList[repairItem] );
    var repairItemPriceList = priceList[repairItem];
    var repairCost = repairItemPriceList[$("#repair").val()];
    console.log( repairCost );

    $("#result").text($("#phones").val() + " -> " + $("#repair").val() + " = " + repairCost);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="phones" name="phones">
  <option value="iphone">iphone</option>
  <option value="blackberry">blackberry</option>
  <option value="HTC">HTC</option>
  <option value="Samsung">Samsung</option>
</select>
<br/>
<select id="repair" name="repair">
  <option value="button">button</option>
  <option value="battery">battery</option>
  <option value="screen">screen</option>
  <option value="back">back</option>
</select>

<hr/>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: This is perfect thank you, is not the way I was thinking of doing it and just goes to show that I have a long way to go to learning javascript. Thank you very much for your time. Thank you to everyone who posted an answer here, it is much appreciated.

Comment: On Stack Overflow, you can always "upvote" his answer if you consider it helpful. And then, if the solution solved your problem, you will want to click on the checkbox to the left of the question to accept it.

Comment: OK great thanks I have accepted the answer as it solved my problem, however it says i don't have the "reputation" required to up vote. As you can see i'am very new to this...thanks

Comment: Glad I could be of help

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick.

```
// Listens for change on either select. You might 
// want to get more specific than 'select' if your 
// page has more elements on it.
$('select').on('change', function(e){

  // Get the value of both elements
  var phones = $('select[name="phones"]').val(); // -> blackberry
  var repair = $('select[name="repair"]').val(); // -> battery, etc.

  // Now do your compare logic ...
  var costs = {
    'iphone': {
      'button': 12.97,
      'battery': 25.64,
      // ...
    },
    // ...
  }

  // Safely determine the cost
  var cost = (costs[phones]) ? costs[phones][repair] : void 0;

  // If there is a corresponding cost,
  if (cost) {

    // ... display logic - this is where you show the cost.
  }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript (no JQuery)

You would specify your datasource somewhere (i.e. a table of costs).  A very simple way of doing this would be to put all the values in a two dimensional associative array:

```
var costs = {};
costs ["iphone"] = {};
costs ["iphone"]["button"] = "£10";
costs ["blackberry"]["button"] = "£5";
...
```

The indexes of your table of costs would be the values of the options in your selects.  You also need to use an ID for each select, not a name.  This makes it easier to find by using document.getElementById rather than document.getElementByName:

```
<select id="phones">
    ...
```

You would then add an onclick event to your button:

```
<input type="button" value="click me" onclick="displayCost()">
```

The function might look something like this:

```
function displayCost() {
    var phones = document.getElementById("phones");
    var items = document.getElementById("repair");

    var phone = phones.options[phones.selectedIndex];
    var item = items.options[items.selectedIndex];

    if (costs[phone.value] && costs[phone.value][item.value]) {
        alert("Repairing the "+item.text+" for your "+phone.text+" will cost "+costs[phone.value][item.value]);
    } else {
        alert("Could not find a cost to repair the "+item.text+" for your "+phone.text);
    }
}
```